# cakephpの初期画面が表示されない

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, aws

AWSのAmazon Linuxにcakephpをアップロードしたのですが、cakephpの初期画面が出ずに以下のようなエラーが出現しています。
AWSのサーバーにはphpをインストール済みです。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
         In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
         We selected 'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/CacheEngine.php on line 60
Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_ja' to File cache in /var/www/html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 328
Warning: /var/www/html/cakephp/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /var/www/html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 385
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine "_cake_core_" is not properly configured.
         Ensure required extensions are installed, and credentials/permissions are correct' in /var/www/html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:186
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') 
#1 /var/www/html/cakephp/app/Config/core.php(374): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) 
#2 /var/www/html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/var/www/html/c...') 
#3 /var/www/html/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(175): Configure::bootstrap(true) 
#4 /var/www/html/cakephp/app/webroot/index.php(104): include('/var/www/html/c...') 
#5 /var/www/html/cakephp/index.php(41): require('/var/www/html/c...') 
#6 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 186
```

追記：nginxを再起動したら、画面が出たのですが、CSSが効いていないようです。。

Answer (score 1):

書き込み権限以外にもPHPの設定が足りていないようですね。

> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/CacheEngine.php on line 60

ようするにdate.timezoneの設定がされていないからUTCとして認識してるということです。
日本で運用する場合は以下の設定をphp.iniなどにすればいいです。

```
date.timezone = Asia/Tokyo
```

Comment: 詳しい設定を見ていないからたぶんですがCSSが聞いていないのは.htaccessが有効になっていないのだと思います。

Answer (score -1):

エラーメッセージを見る限りではキャッシュを書き込むディレクトリの書き込み権限に問題があるようです。

> Warning: /var/www/html/cakephp/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable

ということのようですから、上記のディレクトリにおいてnginxを実行するユーザの書き込み権限の有無を確認してみてください。

cssについてはnginxの設定でドキュメントルートが `/var/www/html/cakephp/app/webroot` を指しているかどうかの確認が必要かと思われます。